# mariadb dynamic column manipulation after wildcard select with php

Tags: php, mariadb

is there a way to extract data from a dynamic column in marida after a wildcard select

For example

```
$db->query("select * from mytable");
```

and my table includes a column that is dynamic.

Any suggestion in this case is welcome as I have problems in declaring the dynamic filed name before the select.

Comment: I think when you use `SELECT *` you just get the blob, not the dynamic columns. To get the dynamic column data you have to use `COLUMN_GET()`

Comment: can you point me to an example? thanks.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dynamic-columns/

Comment: SELECT COLUMN_GET(blob, 'colname' as CHAR) means you know the column name but how can I store the output for a select and then extract data. like SELECT COLUMN_GET(blob) and the read the content?

Comment: It would probably be easiest to use `COLUMN_JSON()` to get all the columns as a JSON object. Then you can use `json_decode()` to convert that to an array.

Comment: thank you! much appreciated!

Comment: Which version?  "Dynamic" dates way back, but I don't think MariaDB had JSON until 10.2.